# Permission denied OsError: [Errno 13] (file in use) Celery - Redis -Django

Tags: linux, django, redis, celery

My process creates a file (in a folder mounted through fstab) through celery-redis, the attempt to modify this file, I have the error Permission denied OSError: [Errno 13].

If restart celery I create the file in a local folder I can change it.

```
fstab:
10.1.1.x:/mount /mount cifs rw,nounix,nosuid,nodev,noexec,user=user,password=***,noperm,sec=ntlmv2  0 0

run celery:
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info

Settings.py:
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is permission issue.File created by celery may not have access to write.Put write permission too wherever you created.